# BoundedSemaphore semaphore vs standard Mutex

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, mutex, semaphore

Does anyone know which of the two locking constructs is faster? 
I have:

```
private static final Object mutex = new Object();

void method() {
    synchronized(mutex) {
        // code
    }
}
```

vs:

```
BoundedSemaphore semaphore = new BoundedSemaphore(1);

void method() {
    semaphore.take();

    try{
        //code
    } finally {
        semaphore.release();
    }
}
```

Thanks, everyone.
Matt

Comment: There is no BoundedSemaphore class in standard Java. Where does that class come from?

Comment: Sorry, this was from this site: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/semaphores.html#bounded  Not sure if there is still a valid comparison since I read the site too quickly before posting.

Comment: `synchronized` blocks are re-entrant, but the `BoundedSemaphore` is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In practice their performance is equivalent.  The BoundedSemaphore in your example actually uses intrinsic locking similar to your first example.  Thus they wouldn't vary noticeably.